# Is it possible to get a reference to MyList<Object> if the listname is a string "myList"

Tags: c#, .net, string, properties, dictionary

I have some lists of the type `ObservableCollection<SampleObject>`
They all end with a letter of the alphabet: lista, listb, listc...
Now i want to make a loop which runs through the alphabet and at every letter it should add an item to the current list.

Example:

```
for (char i = 'a'; i < 'z'; i++)  
{  
    string name = "list" + i;
    name.Add(.....);
}
```

The "name" in this example should be the list where i want to add an item.

Comment: It's _technically_ possible using **Reflection**...but I would go with @SLaks suggestion of a Dictionary.  There are good cases for the use of Reflection; this isn't one of them.

Comment: I saw some questions on stackoverflow where Reflection was used, but i didn't find a solution for my problem with it, because i don't want to get/set a property of the list. I want use **the list** with a string

Answer (score 5):

You want a `Dictionary<char, ObservableCollection<SampleObject>>`, which will have a different collection for each `char`.

Comment: Is there any other solution where i could keep the lists that i made because i have already finished my methods and binding?

Comment: @thalers You wouldn't want to use a solution like that even if it were possible in C#.  It's contrary to the design of the language.

Answer (score 0):

If your lists are declared at class level then reflection can be used to get a reference to them (I still think a Dictionary is a better choice).

Simple example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<string> lista = new List<string>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before:");
        foreach (string value in lista)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }

        for (char i = 'a'; i < 'z'; i++)  
        {  
            string name = "list" + i;
            System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi = this.GetType().GetField(name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
            if (fi != null && fi.FieldType.Equals(typeof(List<string>)))
            {
                List<string> referenceToList = (List<string>)fi.GetValue(this);
                referenceToList.Add("Hello!");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("After:");
        foreach (string value in lista)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```